# eclipse error after updating eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

getting following error after updating eclipse. Any Idea how to solve this problem???? After some time eclipse is being closed and showing error.

[image]

[image: Screen Shot of Error]

Comment: Problem Solved after opening and close eclipse few times. :)